# Laravel5 - get wrong parameters when "hashtag" in my post parameter?

Tags: url, post, laravel-5, hashtag

I want to send a POST request like :

```
{'user_id' => '18', 'content' => 'i like #fish'};
```

But I always get wrong `content` data, only `I like` ;(so `#` means a end symbol in url)? I don't know why?

Comment: Try to skip the hashtag by \. Ex: 'i like \#fish'. Or you can use entity code for hashtag. Entity code for hashtag is: `&#35` (for decimal), `&#x23` (for hex).

Comment: Thanks. It seems that the hashtag used to page location. fixed it.